# Error 404 Page Not Found

Tags: magento2, php

I recently installed magento 2.1.6 and I was trying to view the php info page at **www.mywebsite.com/phpinfo.php** but I'm getting the 404 error but the file is in the root directory where it is supposed to be and I'm using nginx and the nginx user has ownership of the entire magento directory. I ran the chown command just to be sure. I'm not using a cdn or anything fancy.

My full setup is varnish + redis + nginx and I restarted all of them just to be sure. I'm also using php 7.0

What do I need to do to view the php info page?

> UPDATE: I'm getting these errors in my nginx log but I have nothing in
>   my nginx settings preventing this so I'm thinking it is an htaccess
>   file issue

```
2017/05/08 15:01:48 [error] 17024#0: *998370 access forbidden by rule, client: 127.0.0.1, server: website.com, request: "GET /phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1", host: "website.com"
```

> UPDATE #2: I changed the htaccess rules and I'm not getting the 404
>   error anymore but it is redirecting me to the website with the sid
>   added to the end of the url so is there anyway I can turn off this
>   redirect for this file only?

Comment: Please check `.htaccess` & Server Apache weather rewrite module is enabled or not for Redirection

Comment: you can move the file to pub and then try running from there.

Comment: @PankajBhope Moving it to the pub folder seemed to work but it just turned it into a downloadable file and I want it to be a webpage that I can view